# SAP DBTech JDBC: [328]: invalid name of function or procedure: RECORD_COUNT. I don't understand why an error occurs when using RECORD_COUNT ()

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I don't understand why an error occurs when using `RECORD_COUNT ()`.

Do you have a way to assign a record number value to an `INT` scalar variable?

Here is my code:

```
 CREATE table tab (COL_A int);
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2);

    DO (IN inTab TABLE(col_a int) => TAB, OUT v INT => ?)
     BEGIN
     DECLARE i int;
     v = 0;
     FOR i IN 1 .. RECORD_COUNT(:inTab)
     DO
     v = :v + :inTab.col_a[:i];
    
     END FOR;
    END
```

ERROR:...SAP DBTech JDBC: [328]: invalid name of function or procedure: RECORD_COUNT...

I am trainning about sap hana, thank you very much for my help and interest in my question.

Comment: The `RECORD_COUNT` SQLScript function is available in SAP HANA 2 and higher. If your HANA system is a HANA 1 system, then this function is not available.

Comment: @LarsBr. thanks bro so much.

Comment: Converted the comment to an answer; please accept as correct answer so that this question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RECORD_COUNT` SQLScript function is available in SAP HANA 2 and higher. If your HANA system is a HANA 1 system, then this function is not available.